# How can I provide public access to a subset of a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Background**

My research group and I are developing a [database](http://ebi-forecast.igb.uiuc.edu/documentation.html) to store our data and we are building an [software tool](http://128.174.125.122/wiki/index.php/PECAn_Documentation) that simplifies access to these data. The database will holds data that has been published and that we would like to make available, alongside data that has not been published and that belongs to other researchers.

**Objective**

We would like for our work to be easily reproducible, and to this extent, we need to allow the public to run `SELECT` statements on the data. Three possible solutions include:

1. for each publication, create a subset of the database that can be freely downloaded (possibly in a virtual machine so that the dependencies of the software tool are met)
2. for each publication, create a many-to-many lookup table that links data records to publications, and then provide public `SELECT` permissions to access these records. We could easily replicate the database for public use
   Parameterization modules
   Automation of prior generation

However, I have been told that even allowing wildcard statements compromises security, which is why I consider option 1 more plausible. Option 1 would also enable us to archive the database as it was used with a particular publication.

*update:* to clarify, I want the users to be able to reproduce the entire computational workflow, which requires using `SELECT` statements that can join data tables with auxillary data (like covariates, experimental details) in lookup tables.

**Question**

What is the best way to provide public access to a subset of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *distribute* subsets of data as a SQLite database, that is, create a standalone datafile that people can download to their own computers. Many scholars, economists, etc use SQLite to share datasets because it is self-contained and installation is painless (and I should add, cross-platform).

Comment: sounds like a nice solution; can you provide an example of how I could reproduce a subset of a MySQL database as a SQLite database?

Comment: Clunky but tried-and-true: create views for the table-subsets you want to export; export the views in CSV format; import the exported CSV files into SQLite.

Comment: @David: Write a small program (Python is a good language for this) to pull records out of your existing MySQL installation and then re-insert them into your SQLite container, and then you just run that small program every time you need to export a fresh data set.

Answer (score 0):

Create views with appropriate access privileges, and users that can only access these views, but no underlying tables.

Comment: @Mchi I want the users to be able to replicate the entire analysis using the same software that I did.

Comment: Ok... so views having different names than actual tables won't allow for that. So I guess option 1 would be the best one here.

Comment: DB servers used for internal or private applications should ideally not be accessible by host nodes on the Internet.  If they are accessible it should only be when encrypted connections and strong authentication are required.  Otherwise, it's one big attack vector: what happens if the DB software has a buffer overflow or a (lol) stack overflow bug that grants the remote attacker the ability to execute arbitrary code--or worse?  Besides, it's best to let private and public stuff be on different systems so that resource and bandwidth usage can be monitored and kept segregated.